# How to optimize Vite's HMR with a large React and TypeScript codebase?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I've been using Vite with a fairly extensive React application written in TypeScript. While Vite's Hot Module Replacement (HMR) is incredibly fast for smaller projects, I've noticed a slight lag in the HMR as the size of my codebase has grown.

**Project Details:**

1. React Version: 18.x
2. Vite Version: 4.x
3. TypeScript Version: 5.x
4. Codebase: Roughly 200+ components and utilities, spread across multiple modules.

**Observations:**

- The delay is more pronounced when making changes in higher-level components or shared utilities.
- It seems like Vite is re-compiling more than just the changed module.

**What I've attempted:**

- Checked for circular dependencies that might be causing unnecessary re-compiles.
- Ensured that my tsconfig.json settings are optimized and don't have unnecessary includes or excludes.
- Moved some shared utilities to vite.config.js as external dependencies.

**My questions are:**

1. Are there any best practices or configurations for optimizing Vite's HMR with large React + TypeScript projects?
2. Does Vite's HMR performance get impacted by the complexity of TypeScript types and interfaces, and if so, how can this be mitigated?
3. Are there any recommended plugins or tools to profile and understand what's causing the delay in the HMR process?

Thank you for any guidance or insights you can provide!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.